# jqGrid returns a space in empty cells

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am writing some code based around jqGrid and I've come across a problem relating to the rendering of empty cells.

I use JSON to return the data to render and when there is no value, instead of just outputting nothing, jqGrid outputs a space instead. This is causing problems because I need to trigger a function if the cell is empty.

I have looked at the returned JSON using Firebug and it is definitely correct, there is no space being returned.

Looking at the latest jqGrid demo this problem can be replicated:

1. Visit http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
2. Look at any demo grid which contains an empty cell and "Inspect this element" in Firebug.
3. You will note that this demo grid does the same thing

I appreciate this is likely for validity reasons but is there a workaround for this? At the moment my working selector reads:

```
$(".jqgrow td:not(:first-child)")
```

I have tried to use :contains as below to combine them but not had any luck so far:

```
$(".jqgrow td:not(:contains('&#160;'))")
$(".jqgrow td:not(:contains('&nbsp;'))")
$(".jqgrow td:not(:contains(' '))")
```

I would appreciate any assistance!

**UPDATE 1:**

I have produced this jsFiddle which expands on the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/fJZst/

I've copied one line from my table to keep it as simple as possible. On the demo, if you mouse over a cell which doesn't contain a space you'll get an alert. If it does contain a space, you won't. If you substitute the alert for a tooltip in your head, the selector looks good. If I try this in jqGrid the alert always fires so I'm a little more confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.jqgrow tr td').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) != ''
});
```

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer because it would work if I hadn't gone about things another way. I've now output a dash (-) instead of a blank cell, I can then use td:contains as outlined above to achieve my desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom pseudoclass: http://jsfiddle.net/fJZst/1/.

```
$.expr.pseudos.trimmedEmpty = $.expr.createPseudo(function() {
    return function(elem) {
        return $.trim( $.text(elem) ) === "";
    };
});

$(".jqgrow td:not(:trimmedEmpty)").mouseenter(function() {    
    alert($(this).text());
});
```